# How to animate a 3D model in threejs?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I am currently working on a project to show the 3D models in frontend. When you scroll it shows the next models. I am using `gsap` for scrolling, and `three-fiber` with React framework.

You may check the working version [here](https://dbal-react-frontend-dev.herokuapp.com/).

I have created functional component to dynamically get the models and it returns

```js
const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF(file);
<>
            <Environment files="/hdr/san_giuseppe_bridge_1k.hdr" />
            <directionalLight position={[3.3, 1.0, 4.4]} intensity={1} />
            {/* <OrbitControls enableZoom={false} /> */}
            <group>
              <mesh
                castShadow
                onPointerEnter={onHover}
                onPointerLeave={onHoverOut}
                onClick={handleClick}
                position={slide.position}
                ref={slideRef}
                geometry={nodes.Text.geometry}
                material={materials.Material}
                rotation={[Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]}
              >
              </mesh>
            </group>
          </>
```

and it is used in parent component dynamically for each file we get from backend.

I want to apply the animation to the models, but it should be simple animation, thus I think there is no need to create it in Blender. It basically should have "swinging" animation which is like [here](https://arca1000000.com/).

Would anyone help me with the idea of how that can be done? As I understand that animation is like a rotation within `x` and `z` axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it myself by using `useFrame` which acts like a `update` function.

I have introduced several variables in order to calculate the rotation of `x`, `y` and `z`.

```js
  useFrame(({ clock }) => {
    const t = clock.getElapsedTime();
    const swingSpeed = 0.1;
    const swingAmplitude = 0.01;
    const rotationSpeed = 0.4;
    const rotationAmplitude = 0.2;
    const swingY = Math.sin(t * swingSpeed) * swingAmplitude;
    const swingZ = Math.cos(t * swingSpeed) * swingAmplitude;
    const rotationX = Math.cos(t * rotationSpeed) * rotationAmplitude;

    modelRef.current.rotation.y = swingY;
    modelRef.current.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2 + rotationX;

    modelRef.current.rotation.z = swingZ;
  });
```